# Is one failed test enough evidence to replace an RCBO?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, uk

The consumer unit in my shed (in the UK) has an RCBO.

*I pushed the test button and the breaker did not trip.*

I then reset and rearmed the breaker using the lever. It now trips every time I push the test button.

Is that one failed test enough evidence that I need to have the RCBO replaced if I want reliable RCD protection?

(Put another way, how likely are residual current devices to develop intermittent faults, where they trip sometimes but not always?)

Comment: How about testing it with an actual ground fault? RCBOs are typically 30ma.   240V @ 30ma = 7.2 watts.  Just intentionally miswire a dual BS1363 socket with neutral and ground exchanged so all normal current is a ground fault.  Plug in 5 watts (cellphone charger), then 10 watts (iPad/large tablet charger) then 15 watts (both).   And see when it trips.

Comment: @Harper: Thanks for the suggestion. For the sake of argument let's say I do that, and it trips when expected. What will I have learnt from that? Is it possible that the RCD circuitry has some intermittent fault that shows up at some times and not at others? Will I be putting myself at risk by continuing to rely on it for protection?

Comment: It's probably just a subpar test switch.  Then again, if it bothers you, a replacement breaker is cheap peace of mind (at least in the USA; where they start at about $20).

Comment: It sounds like the test button contacts oxidized and moving it a few times cleaned them off.

Comment: People actually test them? The only thing I do with them is pop it myself to see if it's popped. If it pops and then it can reset, then that wasn't it.

Answer (score 2):

You've a couple of options:

- Find a multi-function tester (the type electricians use). They can perform a proper test on the RCD at set amperages and give you a "time to trip" in milliseconds.
- Failing that: a socket tester is a good thing to own. They check the wiring of outlets and some have an RCD test function but less sophisticated than a MFT. You push a button and either the RCD trips or it doesn't. (I've used the Kewtech Loopcheck 107 before)
- Failing that: just replace the RCD. If you can't prove it works you can't rely on it for protection, they can and do fail.